# White screen issue, if an user stays idle in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

In our ASP.NET website one of the page has some tabs in it. Each tab represents different content and moving from one tab to another reloads the entire page. **If I'm currently in one of the tab and stay idle there for around a minute or more and then move on to an another tab, only a white blank screen comes up.**(with no page source code info for that in the browser).

Sadly this same issue is not at all reproducible for the same website in lower testing environment. Issue is occurring only in Production version of the website.

Is there an IIS setting or web.config setting which I should change to resolve this issue. As I believe the source code of the concerned webpage wouldn't be a reason.

Comment: _"Is there an IIS setting or web.config setting which I should change to resolve this issue."_ - I don't think there's a _"show white page after user is idle for one minute"_ setting. You will have to do the analyzing of this error, there's nothing anyone can see from here. Enable the most verbose logging and tracing, take a look with Fiddler, use a different browser, try to pinpoint _who_ is showing a white page and _why_.

Comment: Which authentication mode you use? Do you use session state for storing authenticated user info? Examine how request processed by server when tab switched in browser's developer tools or in Fiddler.

Comment: Is there any long running process executed in your page? Like flash animation, RSS feed, Javascript or AJAX? You can check this using httpwatch or httpfox. You should also check the CPU usage of your server using perfmon.

Comment: Do you use any data bound to time like sessions? Problem depends on how do you load content to your tabs.

Comment: Are you saying that ASP.Net refreshes the page to a blank page? OR, could this be rendering error on your machine? I know that sometimes when I'm using Chrome on one of my machines, switching tabs sometimes ends me up with a blank tab, due to a rendering error or problem with the video card. This is not an ASP.Net problem - in fact, if you can't verify (with Fiddler) that a post-back is happening and returning a blank page, I would say it's definitely a graphics problem and nothing to do with your site. Does it have a lot of media on the page?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because the session timeout has reached the limit ending the session.

You have three possible solutions in this case:

**First**

You can try editing the `web.config` file located on the root of your application to extend the session timeout. Try something like this:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="500">

</sessionState>
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx) you can set `timeout` up to `525,601` minutes (1 year).

**Second**

If it doesn't work and you have access, you can try editing the timeout on IIS:

> Open the IIS, click on the Application Pools, Select the Application
>   pool for your application.
>
> Right Click on that, Select Properties.
>
> In the Performance tab, Set the idle timeout as your desired minutes
>   for "shutdown worker processes after being idle for ..... minutes".
>
> IMPORTANT: Apart from this you have to set the timeout in web.config as said above.

**Third**

You can create an `ajax` function to be executed in background, preventing the session from expiring:

```
function keepSessionAlive(mod) {
mod.open("GET", "blank.html", true);            
mod.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (mod.readyState == 4) {          
        document.getElementById("#blankDiv").innerHTML = mod.responseText;
    }
};  
mod.send(null)
}
setInterval('keepSessionAlive()', 100000);
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: For the lazy. You enter   <sessionState>
Within <system.web>
Like: 
 <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="500">
    </sessionState>
...

Answer (score 1):

Are u usin any custom http module? Can we have a look at the page souce aspx and code behind? It happened to me when i used elmah but in quite different scenario.

Other may be due to the session thing that other pointed out. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would open the chome dev tools or firebug if in firefox.  If in firebug, I would go look at the net and console tabs and see what's actually happening from a network perspective. It should be easy to look at the traffic in dev and compare to production.  I'm guessing they aren't the same, and it would instantly point you in the right direction.

Fiddler is also an option if you want to watch the traffic as if you were a middle-man.